Why isn't my method working for finding value of Fibonacci sequence for nth term?
I am trying to find the value of a Fibonacci sequence given an integer N, representing the nth term using an ArrayList (my logic is that because ArrayList are dynamic and can resize no matter what number is given). For example, 3 should yield 1, 4 should yield 2, etc... Below is my code
public static Integer NacciTerm (int x){

    ArrayList <Integer> arr = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    arr.add(0,0);
    arr.add(1,1);
    
    if (x == 1 || x == 0) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(arr.get(x)));
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 2; i < x; i++)
        {
            int valueOfTerm = 0;
            arr.add(i,valueOfTerm);
            valueOfTerm = arr.get(i-1) + arr.get(i-2);
            arr.set(i,valueOfTerm);
        }
    }
    return arr.get(x);
}

If I try to run it in my main method, whenever I enter a number >= 2, I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at FibonnaciSequence.NacciTerm(FibonnaciSequence.java:36)
    at FibonnaciSequence.main(FibonnaciSequence.java:69)

Any suggestions or reasons why?

Study the edits generously made by dani-vita, to learn proper formatting here.

Step through with a debugger. You'll see that you perform 1 less insertion into the arraylist than you expect. so for x=2, you do not insert at all

but lets format it correctly, including the trace! (@dani, @Basil, @websterweb40)

@websterweb - check your loop if x = 2 - how often will it iterate, that is, check the condition i < x (or i < 2 in this case)

@user85421 I didn't add the closing bracket and changed the indentation because I felt like modifying the original post too much. I'm sure that the missing bracket was a typo, but I felt like it was more on OP to make that edit than us (the community). But thanks for the stack trace formatting!

@dani - it is OK, the missing bracket is no problem, but indentation and maybe the trace - sure, it was more on OP, that is why I normally do not correct it at all, but if it is done, it should be a better example of how to do it (IMHO)

@user85421 gotcha. Very good point! I'll remember that for next time!

@websterweb - another point: the method is doing two different functions: 1) printing the result for  input 0 or 1; 2) returning the result otherwise -- that is not recommended (and an additional error cause too)

You can do this in constant space, and without using lists.

The issue in your code is an off-by-one bug.
This line:
for(int i = 2; i < x; i++)

means that i will never be equal to x, and so that arr.add(i,valueOfTerm);  will only ever add items at indexes strictly below
x.
In order to compute all the Fibonacci numbers up to x included, you simply need to change your loop condition from i < x to i <= x:
for(int i = 2; i <= x; i++)


Be careful when adding elements to a specific index of an ArrayList. The below code handles the ArrayList size issues more gracefully. It checks if i is within the bounds of the ArrayList. This approach avoids the possibility of attempts to access an index that does not exist.
 public static Integer NacciTerm(int x) {
    
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add(0, 0); 
    arr.add(1, 1); 

    if (x == 0) {
        return arr.get(0);
    }
    if (x == 1) {
        return arr.get(1);
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
        if (i >= arr.size()) {
            arr.add(i, 0); 
        }
        int valueOfTerm = arr.get(i - 1) + arr.get(i - 2);
        arr.set(i, valueOfTerm);
    }

    return arr.get(x);
}


suggestions: 1) the two first if can be removed, the condition of the for loop already takes care of values less than 2 (assuming no negatives numbesr); 2) the condition of the third if will always be true, no need to test it (see next point too); 3) instead of adding 0 and later setting the calculated value, just add the calculated value; [ 4) the array is not needed at all, just the last/previous two values must be remembered ]

while this technically answers the question, the actual answer is quite hidden

I will not change your code. In the end you are getting the x element, but remember in the arrays the element always starts counting from 0. This means that the last element in the array would be x-1 instead of an x. This would be your correct solution:
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arr.add(0, 0);
arr.add(1, 1);

if (x == 0 || x == 1) {

    return arr.get(x);

} else {
    for (int i = 2; i < x; i++) {
        int valueOfTerm = 0;
        arr.add(i, valueOfTerm);
        valueOfTerm = arr.get(i - 1) + arr.get(i - 2);
        arr.set(i, valueOfTerm);


    }
}
return arr.get(x - 1);


nope, that is returning the sequence 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ... - the original error is still there (just hidden a bit more)

What your saying is incorrect. The sequence returned is 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 which is the right one. Feel free to debug it.

sorry, maybe you must test it first: https://ideone.com/di9jgD - copy&pasted code directly into the fibo method - Clearly three 1 between 0 and 2

I still see 2 ones here: https://ideone.com/mTfnIk

well, you posted i < x but tested i <= x -- see my comment at the question -- and you are not printing the returned value, are you? (check the forked https://ideone.com/1OW9HK) --- cheating two times :-(

Ohh, yes, I posted the wrong solution. https://ideone.com/SfMyW7 . This is what the guy asks, no? He says that 4 should yield 2, so this fits his expectations :). I think we both know that the 4th element would be 3 but let's not get into the theory too much haha

No, the question seems to be: "I get this error: ... reasons why?" - anyway, your code is returning the 4th entry as 1 (https://ideone.com/mfVWXJ - again a fork of our last posted link) - but I won't continue arguing, have a nice day/night/...

@MartinDM I used your solution . I wanted to ask why is it that I is <= x instead of just I < x ? is there any way to alter the solution so that I could use I < x? I want to really grasp the concept of this so when I face a similar problem, I am able to execute better. thanks

@websterweb - "I used your solution ... why is it that I is <= x" ?? the posted answer does not state i <= x, which I noted couple of times, but I will not explain it any more

@websterweb40 What user85421 is saying is correct. The solution is a flawed since F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, F(2) = 1, F(3) = 2, F(4) = 3 and etc. You can check it here: https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/fibonacci/fibtable.html#:~:text=The%20Fibonacci%20numbers&text=0%201%201%202%20and,610%2C%20987%2C%20...
For your question, if you want to get the correct solution and to use i < x you can simply add the last element manually.  This should be the absolute correct solution if you want also to follow the theory: https://ideone.com/JY2EuT .
P.S: This is definitely not the most optimal solution.

@websterweb40 If you want to try another approach feel free to ask me. I do not know if you can message me on private, but if you do here, it would also be fine.

this: https://ideone.com/60rtI6 is how you'd actually test the function. The array in the function contains the right state, but the return statements are wrong. As you see there are 3 ones in a row in the output.

Read my last comment. Here is your code with the code implemented there: https://ideone.com/aK2DrE . I see 2 ones only...

@MartinDM this last ideone link is quite different from your answer :) Regardless, I'm curious as to why one would write arr.add(x, arr.get(x - 1) + arr.get(x - 2)); instead of having one more iteration in the loop?

You can do this in constant space, without using a list.
public static int fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
      return n;
    }

    int prev = 0, curr = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
      int next = prev + curr;
      prev = curr;
      curr = next;
    }

    return curr;
}

fib(n-1); // from main


If you absolutely want to use a list, you can replace the two variables prev and curr with a list of size 2, and calculate the next index to replace by i % 2 inside the loop. In the end, you return n % 2 element of the list. Even then, an array would be a better fit than a list since the size is known.
